# I need to get the body background-color with Regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, colors, expression

I have this string:

```
"body{
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
}
"
```

I need to the background color (#dfdfdf). The color could be also rgba(120,120,120), so I need to get that color with a regular expression.
I've tried with:

```
^(?=background\-color:\s?)[^;]+$
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Do you want to match the entire line or just the colour code?

Comment: Nope. I couldn't find a solution

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
/\s*background-color:\s*(#[a-fA-F\d]{6})/
```

Use the `match()` method to test the string. It takes a regular expression argument and returns an array containing the result if there is a match or `null` otherwise.

Comment: Yes but I only need the color code of the background-color property. What if I have another CSS rule such as color, text-color?

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is only limited to the color #dfdfdf. Here's one that works:

```
/\s*background-color:\s*(\#[\w]{6}|rgba\(\d{3},\d{3},\d{3}\))/
```

or:

```
/\s*background-color:\s*(\#[\w]+|rgba\(\d+,\d+,\d+\))/
```

But I would rather use the first one since it specifies the amount of letters or digits needed.
You can see that I even added the rgba solution that you asked. So it will match "#dfdfdf" in "body{background-color: #dfdfdf;}" and "rgba(120,120,120)" in "body{background-color: rgba(123,234,233);}"

**EDIT:**
Thinking about it, the color could also be rgb or even the color name, so here is the best solution:

```
/\s*background-color:\s*([\w(),#]+)/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow whitespace at the start of the line `\s*` since you're matching the entire line ( with `^` matching the start and `$` matching the end) and you need a `;` at the end of the line since you've said "one or more non-semicolon characters until the end of the line"

```
^\s*background\-color:\s?([^;]+);$
```

EDIT: The brackets capture the group for more information [see here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: and here it is fixed: http://regexr.com/38n2k You missed off the `^ and $` symbols and needed to enable the multiline flag in that example

Comment: you want to extract it? then put it in brackets, see [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for info.

Comment: In this case, How would it be using brackets?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear, javascript doesn't support lookbehind assertions so a lookahead assertion was no good as instead the things you didn't want captured were absorbed into the `[^;]+` term, it has been removed in this version and the capturing group contains what you want.